# What Solr is telling me in the response payload?

Tags: java, solr

To implement an auto suggest feature, I use a customized subclass of  ***org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchComponent***
And in solrconfig.xml, I configure that component. For example, number of suggestions, the fields that Solr should use to deliver the result.

It is working, however I'm curious about this:
/suggest/q=laptop

```
<lst name="laptop">
 <float name="rank">32809.0</float>
 <int name="total">32809</int>
 <lst name="fields">
   <int name="category">26951</int>
   <int name="brand">5846</int>
   <int name="searchkeyword">4535</int>
 </lst>
</lst>
```

Would you please explain to me what Solr is trying to tell me in that response payload?
I don't know why the search fields are listed and I don't know what those numbers mean and where they come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search fields are most likely being returned based on the configuration you are using for your customized SearchComponent, I am guessing that listing the fields is part of the default configuration for the SearchComponent.

The numbers for each search field are telling you how many documents with your search term (laptop in this case) are found in each field listed.